# Oracle "Number" datatype precision

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are trying to store the values in a table which has a column of "Number" Datatype. The problem arises when we store a very small value , like "0.000001.

```
SQL> desc testing
Name Type   Nullable Default Comments 
---- ------ -------- ------- -------- 
A    NUMBER Y     

SQL> insert into testing values (0.00000001);
1 row inserted

SQL> select * from testing;
         A
----------
     0.001
      1E-5
      1E-8
    0.0001
```

Is there a way, we can store and retrieve the absolute values, as in store, 0.00001 instead of  1E-5.

Comment: Note that this is just a formatting problem, not a precision loss. Number supports 38 significant digits.

Comment: The value **is** stored accurately, it's just SQL*Plus that applies this formatting. Either use `to_char()` or change your NLS settings

Comment: Set required `numformat`, see my answer.

Comment: I don't get the point. Like others said, just a representation issue ...

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a DISPLAY issue. Set **`numformat`** properly.

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(a number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values(0.000000000000001);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t;

         A
----------
1.0000E-15

SQL> set numformat 9D9999999999999999
SQL> select * from t;

                  A
-------------------
  .0000000000000010

SQL>
```

**Update** OP says the above didn't fix the issue when trying to send the number value to the application frontend. There must be something wrong with the **locale-specific NLS settings** that is being used by the application.

If the issue is with just the display, then you could convert it to char using `to_char` and proper format model.

```
SQL> create table t(a number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values(.000000000000000000001);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t;

         A
----------
1.0000E-21

SQL> select ltrim(to_char(a, '9999999D999999999999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')) num from t

NUM
------------------------------
.000000000000000000001

SQL>
```

Note the use of `ltrim`.

Comment: Thanks Lalit,
The main issue is we send this data back in a json format in one of our procedures, when we directly use it in the promt that would work fine, but when we execute in a query and pass it in a json format, we still end up with the E- issue.

Comment: No, why would the value be sent as "E"? The issue is what you see, just the display.

Comment: Thats the same thing we are also tyring to understand, in the front end when the json is sent to .net , they still find it as "E", tying to figure out if any way we can send it formatted properly